# Authenticating the user if the user is not authenticated before making requests

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm developing an Android app that connects to an API. In order to send a get request, I need to send a post request that returns a cookie that authenticates the user.

If I try to send a get request without authenticating, I'm going to get an authentication failure error.

So, I want my app to work like this: if I send a get request and the user is not authenticated, authenticate the user (`authenticate` method) and then send the get request.

I tried to execute this at the beginning of `getUserProfile`, but since `authenticate` is asynchronous, it will execute the get request before the authentication is done. So, it's going to cause an error.

```
if (!AppSingleton.getInstance(context).isUserAuthenticated()) {
        authenticate(context, id);
}
```

---

```
public void authenticate (final Context ctx, int ID) {

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(POST, URL + ID , new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            Log.d(TAG, "getHeaders: " + headers.toString());
            return headers;
        }
        @Override
        protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            Map headers = response.headers;
            AppSingleton.getInstance(ctx).setCookie(headers.get("Set-Cookie").toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "parseNetResponse: ");
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };

    AppSingleton.getInstance(ctx).getRequestQueue().add(request);
}

public void getUserProfile (final Context context, final String userID) {
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    String url = GET_USER_PROFILE_URL + userID;
    Log.d(TAG, url);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Not sure if this is a good practice.
                    ProfileActivity.displayInformation(response);
                    ProfileActivity.toggleProgress();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Cookie", AppSingleton.getInstance(context).getCookie());
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    AppSingleton.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
}
```

PS: I hope the title makes sense.

---

Update: @muratgu, this is the code. I'm doing something wrong, since it's not working.

`getConversationMessages`:

```
    Response.Listener listener = new Response.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Object o) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getConversations: Facebook Login successful. User ID is " + o.toString());
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "getConver - Authentication error: " + volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "getConver - Authentication error: " + volleyError.toString());
        }
    };

    authenticate(context, id, listener, errorListener);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, listener, errorListener) { [...]
```

And `authenticate`:

```
public void authenticate (final Context ctx, int ID, Response.Listener listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(POST, APP_URL + LOGIN_USER_FB_URL + ID , listener, errorListener) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }
        @Override
        protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            Map headers = response.headers;
            AppSingleton.getInstance(ctx).setCookie(headers.get("Set-Cookie").toString());
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };

    AppSingleton.getInstance(ctx).getRequestQueue().add(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the `Response.Listener` and `Response.ErrorListener` to `getUserProfile`.
2. Pass the listeners to `authenticate` as arguments.
3. `authenticate` will call the listeners when it succeeds or fails.
4. `getUserProfile` will do its work within its `Response.Listener`.